# Clueless what I'm doing wrong setting up Spring Boot REST app

Tags: java, spring, rest, maven, spring-mvc

I've been confused as to what I'm doing wrong while setting up what I assume to be a simple Spring Boot Rest api. I do have experience setting up very basic spring app (Still a student) but this is my first time setting up a spring Rest app. I do have the App in the base folder and the app seems to start up but I get a 404 error when I go to "localhost:8080/". I'm assuming maybe my pom is incorrect. I notice that my print trace does not show the repositories being exposed. Thanks for any help.

Main:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }
}
```

BaseEntity:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private final Long id;

    protected BaseEntity() {
        id = null;
    }
}
```

Entity:

```
@Entity
public class Course extends BaseEntity{

    private String title;
    private String url;

    protected Course(){
        super();
    }

    public Course(String title, String url) {
        this();
        this.title = title;
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }
}
```

Repository

```
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface CourseRepository extends CrudRepository<Course, Long> {
}
```

Pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.teamtreehouse</groupId>
    <artifactId>ReviewApi</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>


    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.h2database/h2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.194</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-rest-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-rest-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Print Trace:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java "-javaagent:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar=50324:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/deploy.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/javaws.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jce.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfxswt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/plugin.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/resources.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/ant-javafx.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/dt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/javafx-mx.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/jconsole.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/packager.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/sa-jdi.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/Desktop/ReviewApi/target/classes:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa/1.5.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/1.5.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/1.5.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/1.5.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/1.5.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-logging-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.11/logback-classic-1.1.11.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.1.11/logback-core-1.1.11.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.24/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.24.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j/1.7.24/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.24.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/4.3.7.RELEASE/spring-core-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.17/snakeyaml-1.17.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-aop/1.5.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-aop-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/4.3.7.RELEASE/spring-aop-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.8.9/aspectjweaver-1.8.9.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-jdbc/1.5.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-jdbc-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-jdbc/8.5.11/tomcat-jdbc-8.5.11.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-juli/8.5.11/tomcat-juli-8.5.11.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-jdbc/4.3.7.RELEASE/spring-jdbc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/5.0.12.Final/hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.3.0.Final/jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/javax/persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api/1.0.0.Final/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/javassist/javassist/3.18.1-GA/javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/antlr/antlr/2.7.7/antlr-2.7.7.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/jboss/jandex/2.0.0.Final/jandex-2.0.0.Final.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/dom4j/dom4j/1.6.1/dom4j-1.6.1.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/xml-apis/xml-apis/1.0.b2/xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/common/hibernate-commons-annotations/5.0.1.Final/hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.1.Final.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager/5.0.12.Final/hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/javax/transaction/javax.transaction-api/1.2/javax.transaction-api-1.2.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-jpa/1.11.1.RELEASE/spring-data-jpa-1.11.1.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-orm/4.3.7.RELEASE/spring-orm-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/4.3.7.RELEASE/spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/4.3.7.RELEASE/spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aspects/4.3.7.RELEASE/spring-aspects-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/com/h2database/h2/1.4.194/h2-1.4.194.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web/1.5.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-web-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/1.5.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/8.5.11/tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-el/8.5.11/tomcat-embed-el-8.5.11.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-websocket/8.5.11/tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.11.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-validator/5.3.4.Final/hibernate-validator-5.3.4.Final.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/javax/validation/validation-api/1.1.0.Final/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/classmate/1.3.1/classmate-1.3.1.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.8.7/jackson-databind-2.8.7.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.8.7/jackson-core-2.8.7.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/4.3.7.RELEASE/spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/4.3.7.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/4.3.7.RELEASE/spring-expression-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-rest-core/2.6.3.RELEASE/spring-data-rest-core-2.6.3.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-tx/4.3.8.RELEASE/spring-tx-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/springframework/hateoas/spring-hateoas/0.23.0.RELEASE/spring-hateoas-0.23.0.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-commons/1.13.3.RELEASE/spring-data-commons-1.13.3.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/springframework/plugin/spring-plugin-core/1.2.0.RELEASE/spring-plugin-core-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/atteo/evo-inflector/1.2.1/evo-inflector-1.2.1.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.8.7/jackson-annotations-2.8.7.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.24/slf4j-api-1.7.24.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.7.24/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.24.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/com/jayway/jsonpath/json-path/2.2.0/json-path-2.2.0.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/net/minidev/json-smart/2.2.1/json-smart-2.2.1.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/net/minidev/accessors-smart/1.1/accessors-smart-1.1.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm/5.0.3/asm-5.0.3.jar com.teamtreehouse.App
objc[809]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java (0x106e8c4c0) and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib (0x106f544e0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.5.2.RELEASE)

2017-05-08 19:58:30.877  INFO 809 --- [           main] com.teamtreehouse.App                    : Starting App on Ronalds-MacBook-Pro.local with PID 809 (/Users/ronaldpitt/Desktop/ReviewApi/target/classes started by ronaldpitt in /Users/ronaldpitt/Desktop/ReviewApi)
2017-05-08 19:58:30.880  INFO 809 --- [           main] com.teamtreehouse.App                    : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-05-08 19:58:30.949  INFO 809 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@38364841: startup date [Mon May 08 19:58:30 EDT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-05-08 19:58:32.540  INFO 809 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c315e65f] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-05-08 19:58:33.015  INFO 809 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2017-05-08 19:58:33.040  INFO 809 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2017-05-08 19:58:33.041  INFO 809 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.11
2017-05-08 19:58:33.201  INFO 809 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2017-05-08 19:58:33.201  INFO 809 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2256 ms
2017-05-08 19:58:33.404  INFO 809 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2017-05-08 19:58:33.410  INFO 809 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2017-05-08 19:58:33.411  INFO 809 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2017-05-08 19:58:33.411  INFO 809 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2017-05-08 19:58:33.411  INFO 809 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2017-05-08 19:58:34.119  INFO 809 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2017-05-08 19:58:34.145  INFO 809 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2017-05-08 19:58:34.257  INFO 809 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.12.Final}
2017-05-08 19:58:34.260  INFO 809 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2017-05-08 19:58:34.262  INFO 809 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2017-05-08 19:58:34.308  INFO 809 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2017-05-08 19:58:34.558  INFO 809 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
2017-05-08 19:58:35.091  INFO 809 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
2017-05-08 19:58:35.104  INFO 809 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000230: Schema export complete
2017-05-08 19:58:35.149  INFO 809 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2017-05-08 19:58:36.278  INFO 809 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@38364841: startup date [Mon May 08 19:58:30 EDT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-05-08 19:58:36.404  INFO 809 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2017-05-08 19:58:36.406  INFO 809 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2017-05-08 19:58:36.461  INFO 809 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-05-08 19:58:36.461  INFO 809 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-05-08 19:58:36.536  INFO 809 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-05-08 19:58:36.980  INFO 809 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2017-05-08 19:58:37.083  INFO 809 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
2017-05-08 19:58:37.091  INFO 809 --- [           main] com.teamtreehouse.App                    : Started App in 16.892 seconds (JVM running for 17.809)
2017-05-08 20:36:16.889  INFO 809 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2017-05-08 20:36:16.889  INFO 809 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2017-05-08 20:36:16.918  INFO 809 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 29 ms
```

Comment: Did you create a controller class? 

spring official repo has an example using spring-boot-starter-data-rest which might be easier to get started. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-data-rest

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you are lacking of any classes that exposes your REST services. Spring REST application is made of typically of 3 layers (Controller layer, Service layer & Repository layer ) and of course you can find many other intermediate layers through out the net.

To give you an illustration, the Controllers layer of a simple REST application(typically annotated with @Controller) exposes the REST methods(GET, PUT, POST etc) and it could call the service/repository layer to get information directly from the DB. However in the real world, this is not sufficient, hence the addition of a manager class layer in between the Service layer and Repository layer. The Manager Layers contains all the necessary business logic and could call multiple repositories in a single method to achieve a specific business goal.

Now coming back to your project, it seems that you have the Repository layer but not the Controller / Service layer. So you did not provide a gateway for the clients to access or make a call.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/course")
public class CourseController{


@Autowired
CourseRepository courseRepository;  /**implmentations of the course repository needed**/


@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Course getCourse(){ . // you have to create a courseDto
 Course course = courseRepository.findById(); 

// map  course pojo to coursedto (if needed/subjective)
return course;
}

}
```